# Podio issue: Can't convert string to number

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, podio

I know how to convert a string to a number (parseInt, parseFloat, Math., + Number() etc.).

But this all doesn't work in a PODIO calculation field with a string from a PODIO text field (single line and multi line, and also not from a text type calculation field). 
Text in textfield: 123

```
var str = @textfield;
Number(str)
```

Also when I tried with parseInt(str) etc. result is always the error msg.: Not a valid number.

It works e.g when str = "123", but not when I want to use the token @textfield. It works also when str is a category field token (and categorie is 123).

Any suggestion how I can convert a string to a number using a @textfield token?

TIA
Rainer

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that you don't check whether @textfield is an empty string. E.g. `parseInt('', 10);` will result in `NaN`

Comment: No, @textfield is not empty. Text is "123", `@textfield.length` = 3, `typeof @textfield` = string , type of calculation field = number.
When I use @textfield in a calcultion field = text type I get 123.

Answer (score 0):

You just use `@Email Text` in the calculation field.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found this!  you need to add || 0 at the end of the code line with the conversion.  Then the number will be accepted in PODIO calc. field.
ex.

```
var x='123.48';

y=Number(x);// result is not a valid number

var x='123.48';

y=Number(x) || 0;// this works
```

Thought I'd save someone else the time I spent hunting this one down.....whew!